# How to install ubuntu on hundreds or thousands of servers?

Tags: system-installation, cloud, cluster

This is just a question out of curiosity, but I would like to know how can you install ubuntu on hundreds/thousands of machines at the same time?

Say I have 100 computer that come with no OS how can I install Ubuntu on them?
Shall I proceed with the installation manually on each of them? If not what are the technologies and tools one should know?

Comment: I  am not a networking expert however, I think [this official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) covers it.

Comment: @g_p wow, could be the answer(+1), but i think he wants to install it really on the machines.

Comment: I would try to modify a boot disc( or usb? ) so that automatically at boot from the disc the system with a specified configuration is installed. see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO

Comment: You use kickstart and PXE (netboot) http://fai-project.org/ . IMHO Fedora / RHEL / Centos / Scientific are better (kickstart plus netboot iso) and it also depends on if you are talking gphysical servers or virtualization. With virtualixation you would clone a disk image or use LXC. See also http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html

Comment: I think netboot would be an option, but for something like virtualbox( do I understand you right?) he woulde need to install a system on the machine first.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen as I sad....

Comment: I folks thanks for all the answers! As some of you guessed correctly I am curious about physical servers/computer. I am aware of some technologies for virtul machines, but I have no idea about physical ones. Also I do not think mine is a duplicate question: while having an installation process that does not require manual inputs is certainly required, there is still the issue of deploying them on the target machines.

Comment: @LittleByBlue- How does remastering the arch CD apply to this question ? any cd will work as is, the OP wants to automate the install which translates into netboot + kickstart, either with Ubuntu or Fedora. Perhaps you have a link to kickstart (or similar) arch ?

Comment: on debian based distro such as ubuntu, use preseed to automate every expect of options during installation.